# Вывод строки из массива если её длинна равна четырём

Tags: javascript

Пишу функцию, которая принимает массив, и выдаёт другой на выходе , в котором элементы длинна которых = 4.

```js
var output = [];

function friend(friends){
  
  for (var i = 0; i < friends.lenght; i++) {
    if (friends[i].length === 3) {
      output.push(friends[i]);
    }
    return output;
  }
}


console.log(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark", "Kieran", "Mark"]));
```

не получается, не пойму почему?

Comment: `длинна которых = 4` и `=== 3` и может быть `2 * 2 = 5`?

Comment: @Grundy не получается `function friend(friends){
  var res = friends.filter(el=>el.length == 3);
  return res;
}` что делаю не так?

Comment: @stas0k, что именно не получается? в res ты запихиваешь все элементы с длиной 3 - так как у тебя в массиве нет таких элементов ты и получаешь пустой массив

Comment: да ошибся , думал с 0 нумеруется длинна

Comment: нумеруются элементы. Длина не нумеруется, это просто число показывающее количество.